# Creating Multidimmensional Datasets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a problem and given the dimension size am having a hard time conceptualizing what I need to do. I have various csv files in the format:

```
Date     Close    Volume  Target
1/1/18   120.1    223     0
1/2/18   112.1    219     1
1/3/18   175.1    224     0
```

Each of these csv files represents an individual sample (historical stock data for one company).

I would like to take multiple csv files similar to this and concatenate them so that they are contained in a single dataset. So, that instead of each date in a csv file being an observation (sample), now the entire set is a sample (one stock). With each having its date samples within. I am then planning on running this through a logistic regression algorithm to predict the target. The only way that I can conceptualize this happening is to do something like:

```
Date     Close    Volume  Target
1/1/18   120.1    223     0
         88.1     120     1
1/2/18   112.1    219     1
         78.1     230     0
1/3/18   175.1    224     0
         89.1     112     1
```

To me this set up doesn't make that much sense though because now there is overlap? Each price set is distinctly different but now in the same column.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. Working code examples are very helpful. Some added context, as well, it is for concatenating a set of stock csv files so maybe someone has worked with this kind of data before.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, but you can add one more column indicating which file the data come from, and sort the whole data according to that column.

Comment: Looks like you can check ensembling

Comment: @Wen-Ben that is what I was thinking, ensembling 100 different models (for the NASDAQ 100) but I have never done this method before so I am not sure how easy it would be to do.

Comment: http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/12/27/a-kagglers-guide-to-model-stacking-in-practice/， also good to mention make sure your do not have imbalanced data :-)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Follow up, my understanding is that this combines multiple models on the same dataset not different datasets on the same model.

Comment: @QFII think about , you already have n fold(number of tickets) of data